# Difference between "hätte etw. machen sollen", "sollte etw. machen", "soll etw. gemacht haben"

Tags: english-to-german

I've been asking this question many German natives but I received very contradicting feedback. Maybe I am asking in a bad way.

In English when you say

> "He should have done this"

it can mean one of 2 things:

1. > He didn't do, it was important though, he should have done it.
2. > He intended to do it, he said he was going to do it, he should have done it by now. I am not sure though whether he have done it or
   >   not.

So how do these relate to the German sentences:

> Er sollte das machen
>
> Er hätte das machen sollen
>
> Er hätte das machen müssen
>
> Er soll das gemacht haben
>
> Er muss das gemacht haben

Also, I want to know the passive form of these meanings. So what is the German alternative for:

1. > This should have been done (It wasn't done, and I am pissed)
2. > This should have been done (Someone said he was going to do it, not sure though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first meaning (*not time related*) could be translated as

> Er hätte es/das machen sollen/müssen.
>
> Er hätte es/das gemacht haben müssen.

However, the second one is a very complicated construct which is not used very often.

Also the following fits:

> Er hätte es/das besser gemacht.
>
> Besser wäre es gewesen, hätte er es/das gemacht.

Although this has a very similar meaning, technically it is a different sentence (in English: `It would have been better to do it`).

The second meaning (*time related*) could be related to:

> Er sollte es/das gemacht haben [bis jetzt/heute].

In German, usually additional phrases like `bis jetzt` (by now) are used to express the meaning more clearly.

The other sentences you provided do not fit, since they have a different meaning:

> Er sollte es/das machen.

```
He was supposed to do it/this.
```

> Er muss es/das gemacht haben.

```
He must have done it/this.
```

Both **passive** forms can be expressed as

> Es/Das hätte gemacht werden sollen.

However, to express the *I am pissed* meaning you can use `müssen` instead of `sollen` and to express the time related meaning again you can use an additional phrase like `bis jetzt`:

> Es/Das hätte bis jetzt/heute gemacht werden sollen.